# Using onTouchListener or Onclick Listener on a View with disabled widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a situation where I have a view (linear layout) with disabled (child) widgets and I want a message to alert the user to click an edit button (which enables the widgets) when they try to change any values.

At the moment there's a listener setup on the View which bring up a toast but the listener doesn't work on the areas where widgets have been disabled, all other areas, however, work as expected (e.g. blank areas).

I've tried using onTouch and onClick listeners on the view - no difference.

I've also tried using android: clickable/focusable/enabled in the layout XML file but either they don't work or new issues are created as I have a mixture or buttons/edit text/radio buttons/checkboxes on the page.

Does anyone have any ideas or alternative approaches to resolve this problem?

Thanks very much in advance for any help.